# What version of java (if any) comes with Windows 7 default install?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

What version of java (if any) comes with Windows 7 default install?  Is java even installed by default in windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java does not come with Windows. Some PC Vendors do include Java preinstalled (i.e Dell). It depends on the Vendor.

Comment: +1 - this is more strictly correct than mine.  I altered my wording to reflect what I was thinking when I first answered.

Answer (score 3):

Java is not bundled into Windows since the lawsuit.

Comment: For reference, this is referring to the [2001 lawsuit between Sun and Microsoft](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074908/sun--microsoft-settle-java-lawsuit.html).